# Show that the $G_f$ of $f$ is compact and connected on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: functions, continuity, compactness, connectedness

**Let $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Define the graph of $f$ as $G_f:= \{(x, f (x)) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x \in [a,b]\}$. Show that the $G_f$ of $f$ is compact and connected on $\mathbb{R}^2$.**

Demonstration:

Let's define first $F: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such as $F(x):= (x, f(x)); \forall x \in [a,b]$.
Now, let's show that $F$ is continuos on $[a,b]$.
Note that by hypothesis, given $ x_0 \in [a, b]$ and for $\varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such as $|x-x_0| < \delta \Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|< \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2}}$.

On the other hand $||F(x)-F(x_0)||=||(x,f(x))-(x_0-f(x_0))||= ||(x-x_0, f(x)-f(x_0))||= \{ |x-x_0|^2 + |f(x)-f(x_0)|^2\}^\frac{1}{2}$

According to the above we have
$||F(x)-F(x_0)||\leq \{ |x-x_0|^2 + |f(x)-f(x_0)|^2\}^\frac{1}{2}$

In this way if $|x-x_0|< min \{ \delta , \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2}}\}$.
We get that $||F(x)-F(x_0)||<\{(\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2}})^2 + (\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2}})^2\}^\frac{1}{2} = \varepsilon$

Which shows that $F$ is continuous in $[a, b]$.
How [a,b] is compact on $\mathbb{R}$, from the result seen in class it is concluded that the $F([a,b])=G_f$ is compact.

**I still need to show that it is also connected.**

Comment: $G_f$ is the image of $[a,b]$ under  the continuous map  $x \to (x,f(x))$.

Comment: Continuous maps preserve compactness and connectedness

Comment: The second to last paragraph is a bit confusing; do you need to show that $[a,b]$ is connected? If so, then a subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is connected if and only if it is an interval.